# Compass / scout import

Tags: compass-sass, compass-geolocation, scout-sass

I just started with compass with scout for the GUI. 
I'm trying to follow along with a demo and am a bit confused about @import. When I do 
    @import "compass" everything compiles fine. However when I try to import @import "scss/normalize" which is in compass/scss/_normalize.scss i get

> > > Change detected at 14:59:07 to: screen.scss
> > >       error screen.scss (Line 2: Invalid CSS after "@import "compass"": expected selector or at-rule, was "@import "scss/n...")
> > >       overwrite screen.css

What exactly is  @import "compass"  doing? what file is that importing? Or is a folder from where I installed scout in program files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out. you need  a ; after each import statement. duh.